# An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again. In Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have configure Authorize.Net Payment method in magento 2, 
But i am getting "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again" after click on place order.

Also sometimes its work's perfectly. So i need to know is ti magento issue or payment gateway issue. Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: now check debug.log and exception log which erorr

Comment: Getting requested parameters log in debug.log and no any exception log

Comment: @RaviOza have you found any solution

Answer (score -2):

To know the exact reason why it is happen so, please open below file:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement.php

than comment out the try, catch and put code to place order directly as below:

*Replace below function*

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //var_dump($e);
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
    return $orderId;
}
```

**To**

```
public function savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface $paymentMethod,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface $billingAddress = null
) {
    $this->savePaymentInformation($cartId, $paymentMethod, $billingAddress);
    //try {
        $orderId = $this->cartManagement->placeOrder($cartId);
    /*} catch (\Exception $e) {
        //var_dump($e);
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again.'),
            $e
        );
    }*/
    return $orderId;
}
```

Now, try to place order again. You will be able to see the detailed error in log file or may be in console.